# Sorting of rows based on 3 date columns in from different tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to sort records based on updated dates columns from 3 different tables,
I have a followig set of data

```
Table A 
   Id data updatedOn
   1   abc 2017-02-11 09:34:40

Table B
  Id question updatedOn
   1  xyz     2017-02-11 09:35:40 
   1  pqr     2017-02-11 09:40:40 

Table C

  Id quote updatedOn
   1  300$ 2017-02-11 09:37:40
```

Now my result should be

```
  Id question quote a.updatedOn        b.updatedOn          c.updatedOn 
   1  pqr     300  2017-02-11 09:34:40 2017-02-11 09:40:40  2017-02-11 09:37:40
```

but the result is

```
  Id question quote a.updatedOn        b.updatedOn          c.updatedOn 
   1  xyz     300  2017-02-11 09:34:40 2017-02-11 09:35:40   2017-02-11 09:37:40
```

Since question `pqr` is updated latest.

I tried following query

```
SELECT a.updatedOn,b.updatedOn,c.updatedOn FROM `A` a
left join B b on a.id= b.id 
left join C c on c.id = a.id
group by id having a.id = 7
order by ifnull(a.updatedOn,0)
DESC,ifnull(b.updatedOn,0) DESC,
     ifnull(c.updatedOn,0) DESC
```

The problem is if I update data in first table it comes at top in result that is ok, but if I update for second and third for second time it wont get shown in descending order as what expected.

also I tried above query with GREATEST function on dates columns 
but no luck.

Please Help.
Thanks.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: show output with table structure

Answer (score 0):

You are not using aggregation function so you should use distinct and where instead of group by and having

```
SELECT distinct a.updatedOn,b.updatedOn,c.updatedOn 
FROM `A` a
left join B b on a.id= b.id 
left join C c on c.id = a.id
WHERE  a.id = 7
order by greatest(a.updatedOn,b.updatedOn,c.updatedOn)  desc
```